# is there any solution to do instantiate tracingfilter in springmvc 3 version?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'tracingFilter' must be of type [javax.servlet.Filter], but was actually of type [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:5037)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Client provide this code to use in application.

@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean tracingFilter(Tracer tracer) {
        TracingFilter tracingFilter = new TracingFilter(tracer,
                getServletFilterDecorators(),
 DEFAULT_SKIP_PATTERN);
        Filter filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(tracingFilter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singletonList("/*"));
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        filterRegistrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

Comment: This above bean specific to springboot. But we need the above same type bean for spring mvc 3 version.
If I  use springboot dependency in our spring mvc application, then above mentioned exception display in logs. 
Kindly need your suggestion.